# How to dynamically set the variable containing the string resource id in Kotlin Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.vocabdaily.Activities

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.vocabdaily.R

class Definition : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_definition)
        val title: TextView = findViewById(R.id.definition_title)
        val position = intent?.extras?.getInt("word")
        title.text = getString(R.string.word1)
    }
}
```

I want the R.string.word1 to instead dynamically change to the value of position.

So if position is 0 it would be R.string.word0. If position is 1 it would be R.string.word1. How could I do this?

Comment: You can use `resource.getIdentifier`, but it's very error-prone practice I'd advice against. If possible just put your words into a [string-array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray) and resolve the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
val position = intent?.extras?.getInt("word") ?: -1
val stringId = resources.getIdentifier("word$position", "string", packageName)
title.text = getString(stringId)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Just as a follow up question what does packageName do?

Comment: It returns the `applicationId` of your application as defined in your app `build.gradle` file